# Android - How to add system service with java library?

Tags: android, service, jar

I need your help. Is it possible to add a system service that uses a java library (.jar file)?

Comment: Generally speaking, StackOverflow is more for SDK development than it is for modifying the OS itself. You might consider using one of the Google Groups on http://source.android.com.

Comment: k..I hoped someone might know this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution :)
You can add a static java library in the Android.mk with some commands

--> http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/build_cookbook.html#staticJava

Comment: That let's you use a `.jar` file but it's not adding a system service for you. You still need to add it to [`SystemServer.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java) somehow.

Comment: Yes I know how to add a system service but the thing was to add the library to Android that the service has the possibility to use the lib